# Check/Uncheck boxes when another is clicked in javascript

Tags: checkbox

Trying to clear 2 check boxes when another is clicked. I've searched for this answer and have tried using information from the examples but for some reason nothing I try works.  Here is the code I am currently using.

```
function control()
{
/*var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');
var three = document.getElementById('three');*/

if(document.forms[0].one.checked == true)
{
    document.forms[0].two.checked == false;
    document.forms[0].three.checked == false;
}

if(document.forms[0].two.checked == true)
{
    document.forms[0].three.checked == false;
    document.forms[0].one.checked == false;
}

if(document.forms[0].three.checked == true)
{
    document.forms[0].one.checked == false;
    docuemnt.forms[0].two.checked == false;
}
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" name="getArea">
<input type="checkbox" onClick="control()" name="one">Standard Shipping<br />
<input type="checkbox" onClick="control()" name="two">Overnight Shipping<br />
<input type="checkbox" onClick="control()" name="three">Priority Shipping<br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what happens when you click one of checkbox?

Comment: when i click a checkbox, it puts a check in the box. if you click each one it will put checks in all of them without removing a check in the other boxes

Comment: so at a time only 1 checkbox will be checked? if that is the case why dont you use radio buttons

Comment: the assignment specifies check boxes only

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying something like below?

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

function control(idSelected)
{
/*var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');
var three = document.getElementById('three');*/

if(idSelected==1)
{
    document.forms[0].two.checked = false;
    document.forms[0].three.checked = false;
}

if(idSelected==2)
{
    document.forms[0].three.checked = false;
    document.forms[0].one.checked = false;
}

if(idSelected==3)
{
    document.forms[0].one.checked = false;
    docuemnt.forms[0].two.checked = false;
}
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" name="getArea">
<input type="checkbox" onClick="control(1)" name="one">Standard Shipping<br />
<input type="checkbox" onClick="control(2)" name="two">Overnight Shipping<br />
<input type="checkbox" onClick="control(3)" name="three">Priority Shipping<br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep got it just as this was posted. I screwed up the assignement operator. Thanks.

Comment: You might even have to consider the conditions as in your code if the first checkbox is selected , it'll remain selected ... is that the requirement ?